# What would be the most optimal/logical way to store answers to pre-determined yes or no questions to the database

Tags: python, django, database

I've been thinking:

What would be the most optimal/logical way to store user answers to pre-determined 'yes or no' questions to the database. Note: the question model is in a one-to-one relationship with the user model.

No. of Questions: 25

A: Store the questions as straight boolean variable/column to the database.

```
Per user x 25 columns
```

B: Store the questions as 'question' and boolean 'answer' to the database.

```
Per user x 25 question rows, 1 user x 25 answer rows
```

Which is faster? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: This question is slightly off-topic for Stack Overflow, but using columns for user-definable properties is frowned upon. You can't easily create an admin site to add more questions in the future, for example.

Comment: @Selcuk thanks! I will be using option B just because you've said option A is frowned upon.

Comment: It's up to you and to your use case. Note that in option B you can't use a one-to-one relation. Also if the question set is the same for all users it makes more sense to use a many-to-many relation between User and Question and use a through-table for answers. You will still have to assure referential integrity (i.e. you can't have the same question asked multiple times to the same user).

Comment: @Selcuk got it. Thanks!